# Inline elements not collapsing whitespace before the end of the tag, in modern browsers?

Tags: css, whitespace

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9e81ytwg/

```
<div>Foo <span> Bar </span> Baz</div>

*{font-size:30px;font-family:monospace}
span{background:red;}
```

Rendered in **legacy browsers**:

[image: m]

Rendered in **modern browsers**:

[image: m]

- **BEFORE Bar there are TWO spaces, they get collapsed into ONE single space that appears WHITE**
- **AFTER Bar there are TWO spaces, they get collapsed into ONE single space that appears RED**

why this difference? and why it's different from how it used to work just few months ago?

**Is there a specific spec / point where the rendering changed?** I'd have expected it working like it used to in legacy browsers. Or is it a bug?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9e81ytwg/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9e81ytwg/2/

Comment: I was going to show [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9e81ytwg/3/)? The reasoning is because you're pressing **space** (which is counted as a character)

Comment: guys how about reading, sometimes?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Your element just contains some space which is browser counted as a character.

Comment: @jbutler483 you don't say

Comment: @Mardzis why the behavior changed? and why the space BEFORE Bar is not treated as the space AFTER Bar?

Comment: @Mario: So why would you *expect* it to remove spacing? As my fiddle shows, the space **before** the bar is being counted, as is any space after. I really don't get what you're asking, as (to me anyway), it's working just as it should.

Comment: semi-related: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/white-space-handling/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model (emphasis mine):

> If 'white-space' is set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line'
>
> 1. every
>      tab (U+0009) is converted to a space (U+0020)
> 2. any space (U+0020)
>      following another space (U+0020) — **even a space before the inline**, if
>      that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or
>      'pre-line' — is removed.

The behaviour you are seeing is therefore completely correct: all whitespace is collapsed from back to front, and therefore the preceding whitespace is not red (it collapsed into the 'space before the inline') and the trailing one is (as the other spaces collapse into it).

I have no clue which 'legacy browsers' you refer to but likely this was a bugfix in their engine somewhere along the way, as this has been in the standards like this for several years.

**Update:** the standards were [*not* explicit on this back in 2008](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/text.html#white-space-prop) when CSS2 was last updated, and it [*was* explicit in the 2011 CSS 2.1 final drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/PR-CSS2-20110412/text.html#white-space-model). Hence it's not really strange that browsers weren't uniform on how to handle this.

Comment: "standard" is a weird word sometimes, because the actual standard behavior implemented by all browser was the other one. but thank you for your answer, and for actually reading my question, because I've had lot of downvotes from people who didn't actually read it :)

Comment: Drafts of CSS 2.1 has been explicit on this processing model since [2003](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-CSS21-20030128/text.html#white-space-prop)

Comment: Keep in mind that the CSS2 recommendation dates back to 1998 - anything that was changed between then and '08 were probably non-breaking changes. The addition of section 16.6.1 to CSS2.1 is documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q115).